# Rails Migrations: Foreign key and indexing column fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, migration

I developed a Ruby on Rails 5 application and deployed it to a production environment, after running rake db:migrate I noticed that I wasn't using  **foreign_key: true** and  neither **index: true** for my general relations between tables. Question is: Will this affect database performance and should I generate new migrations just to add indexes and foreign keys references to my columns? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[From Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions):

### 2.2 Schema Conventions

Active Record uses naming conventions for the columns in database tables, depending on the purpose of these columns.

> Foreign keys - These fields should be named following the pattern
>   singularized_table_name_id (e.g., item_id, order_id). These are the
>   fields that Active Record will look for when you create associations
>   between your models.
>
> Primary keys - By default, Active Record will use an integer column
>   named id as the table's primary key. When using Active Record
>   Migrations to create your tables, this column will be automatically
>   created.

You must know more about `ActiveRecord` Look here how it works [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models)

I suggest you to read about `belongs_to` and `has_many` relations

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are going to do, if you have relations where the foreign key is needed, you will need to create those migrations, otherwise you wont be able to access them.

When it comes to db performance it doesnt matter really